# Hyper V Ubuntu 16.04 using host's VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, hyper-v, ubuntu-16.04

I have a windows 10 laptop that has a working VPN connection. I've used Hyper V to install ubuntu 16.04 and have it up and running. I've been trying to get the ubuntu 16.04 VM to use the host's vpn connection? Is it possible? I followed instructions given [here](https://erictummers.com/2015/06/10/use-vpn-from-host-in-hyper-v-vm/) which talks about how to get it going for a VM running IE browser. I'm unable to figure out how to set ubuntu 16.04 such that *all* traffic gets routed through the vpn and not just browser traffic.
Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Is the Ubuntu machine able to connect to the internet through the host, just not through the VPN? Or does Ubuntu have no successful connection?

Comment: The ubuntu machine is able to connect to the internet on its own, no issues there.

Comment: Are you using routing or bridging for your VM? Is your laptop redirecting all traffic through the VPN, or only some network routes?

Comment: My laptop is routing all traffic through the VPN. I believe its a bridge for the VPN but not sure. I followed exactly the steps given [here](https://blog.couchbase.com/hyper-v-run-ubuntu-linux-windows/) under create a hyper-v switch section.

Comment: I meant a bridge for the VM, not VPN.

Comment: VPN by its nature is a virtual private network, most VPN clients won't share the connection, since they're not supposed to.  Have you tried using the default virtual switch (which is NAT) and shares the host's network connection.  When you create a new virtual switch, this sets up a separate vNIC for Ubuntu which wouldn't get shared by the VPN.

Comment: Iven't tried that. Could you let me know the steps I need to follow please?